# How to implement help pages with Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin Forms application with couple of pages and I would like to implement help pages. I would like help to be semi-transparent layer on top of original page. This layer would contain arrows and texts that explain functionality. Any tips how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a popup could help you

this is a [plugin](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) I use often

You can create your CustomPage and Push / Pop it in front of a Page

```
// Use these methods in PopupNavigation globally or Navigation in your pages

// Open new PopupPage
Task PushAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true) // Navigation.PushPopupAsync

// Hide last PopupPage
Task PopAsync(bool animate = true) // Navigation.PopPopupAsync

// Hide all PopupPage with animations
Task PopAllAsync(bool animate = true) // Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync

// Remove one popup page in stack
Task RemovePageAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true) // Navigation.RemovePopupPageAsync
```

Comment: It is great plugin. Thank you for that. Can it be semi-transparent? I would like to put couple of arrows and text boxes in and everything between it should be semi-transparent.

Comment: It visualizes a ContentPage. If you can have a semi-transparent contentpage, the answer is yes

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this by creating a custom View that you can reuse throughout your Xamarin Forms pages. If you bind the view you can provide the appropriate help text through each ViewModel for the given pages. By binding the views visibility to whether or not the info button was tapped you can show and hide it as needed.

```
<local:HelpView Text="{Binding HelpText}" IsVisible="{Binding ShowHelp}" />
```

Comment: And how to implement HelpView?

Comment: That is totally up to you. It is simply a custom View that you can style as you want to. Create a Forms ContentView from the New Item dialog and add your controls such as labels etc.